# Google Calendar error 403

Tags: google-calendar-api, http-status-code-403

My app with google calendar show this error:

The server had a problem handling your request.
com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: Forbidden
Forbidden<
Error 403

The problem it is in this code:

CalendarFeed resultFeed = service.getFeed(feedUrl, CalendarFeed.class);

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer your question:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol

```
This API is a subject to the Deprecation Policy and will be shutdown on November 17, 2014. Please use APIv3 instead.
```

Comment: Now with the api v3 is possible to do user authentication with only the login information (username / password)?

Comment: I believe you need to now generate an API key with Google. Sorry, I'm not that skilled. I just knew the answer as I was looking into a similar issue!

Comment: Thanks the same for the help!

Comment: You will also need to get an Oauth2 token if you are accessing user information which is not public. See the get started guide on V3: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/firstapp and the Oauth2 documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2